# How to access the k8s services from AppEngine development server

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine

Too much struggles, I need to share.

Need: `GET`/`POST` on `https://ip_cluster_/apis/v1/xxx` from the `dev_appserver` (for local testing)

Error: `Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL`

Cause: the k8s cluster endpoint use a autosigned certificate

Tries:

- Use a Let's Encrypt certificate with ingress. Fails because Let's encrypt needs a DNS
- Asks to AppEngine to do an unsecure connexion : globally with `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY: 0` in `main.app` and locally with `validate_certificate=None` with `url_fetch` or `verify=False` with `requests`. Fails because unsecure SSL connexion with autosigned certificate is not allowed in AppEngine. PR : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-compat-runtime/pull/124
- Get cert/key from `https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<my-gcp-project>/locations/<location>/clusters/<my-cluster>`, decode base64, write in files, use them with `cert=('cluster_k8s.cert', 'cluster_k8s.key')` in `requests`. Fails because local certs support is disabled in AppEngine. Using them with curl works just fine. Obviously.
- Get cert/key like above and add them as custom certs in google cloud sdk: `gcloud config set core/custom_ca_certs_file=my_cert.pem`. Fails because life is hard.
- Get cert/key like above and append them to the google cloud sdk one:

  `cd /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cacerts/
  cat my_cert >> urlfetch_cacerts.txt`

  Fails because life is even harder.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : use kubectl proxy like `kubectl proxy --port=8001`

The k8s services are know reachable in http from `http://localhost:8001`

Switch endpoint in your AppEngine with code like:

`if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
  # Production
else:
  # Local development server`